# Node.js while loop return deffered result

Tags: node.js, function, while-loop, callback

What I'm trying to do is this, I have 2 users an attacker and a defender. I want the call hit() function until one of the runs out of Health, hit() should be called on turns, first attacker, then defender, then attacker and so on until one reaches 0 hp.

My idea was to do it with a while loop, with current code all I get is the console.log from hit(), an infinite loop. The data from hit() is returned correctly if it's not inside a loop ... I could simply just work in the while loop and not use the hit function but it would mean repeating a lot of code, since there will be a few things to consider before a hit actually happens.

If you have an alternative to the while loop I'm open to ideas, also I should mention I'm new at node so keep it as simple as possible please. Thank you.

This is the relevant part of the code:

```
var prepareAttack = function(attacker,defender) {
    connectdb().done(function(connection) {
        query(connection,'SELECT * FROM members WHERE name = ?', attacker).done(function(result) {
            var attackerData = result[0][0]
            query(connection,'SELECT * FROM members WHERE name = ?', defender).done(function(result) {
                var defenderData = result[0][0]
                var attackerHp = attackerData.hp
                var defenderHp = defenderData.hp
                while(attackerHp > 0 && defenderHp > 0) {
                    hit(attackerData,defenderData).done(function(result){
                        defenderHp = result;
                        console.log(defenderHp)
                    })
                    hit(defenderData, attackerData).done(function(result) {
                        attackerHp = result;
                        console.log(attackerHp)
                    })
                }

            })
        })
    })
}
var hit = function (attackerData, defenderData) { // simplified code just relevant parts inside.
    console.log('hitting')
    var defer = Q.defer()
    var newHp = 0;
    defer.resolve(newHp)
    return defer.promise

}
```

Comment: var defenderData = result[0][0] returns the first value from the first result row of your database query. If this is a serialized json or object, you need to deserialize. In any case, defenderData.hp will be undefined. This will also be the case for attacherData.hp.

Comment: I already tested those and right number is retrieved. result[0] contains all the returned rows so first row is result[0][0]